# Compute following operator norms

Tags: functional-analysis

The operators are in the dual of $C([a,b])$, $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$, $a<b$
\begin{align*}
&(a) \quad f(x) := \int_a^b x(t) d t, \quad x \in C([a, b])\\
&(b) \quad f(x) := x(t_0), \quad t_0 \in [a, b], x \in C([a, b])
\end{align*}

---

For (a) I first looked at an estimate upwards.
$$\|f\|=\inf \|f(x)\|=\inf \|\int_a^b x(t)dt\|_{\infty}\leq \inf \|x\|_{\infty}\int_a^b dt=(b-a)\|x\|_{\infty}$$
$$\Rightarrow \|f\|\leq b-a$$
But since constant functions are also in $C([a,b])$ and for any constant function $g$ we have: $\|\int_a^b g(t)dt\|_{\infty}=\|g\|_{\infty}(b-a)$, the operator norm must be equal to $b-a$ since it must be true for any continuous function.

---

(b) looked even simpler.
$$\|f\|=\inf\|f(x)\|=\inf\|x(t_0)\|_{\infty}\leq \|x\|_{\infty}$$
$$\Rightarrow \|f\|\leq1$$
And for some continuous functions $g$ we have that $\|g(t_0)\|_{\infty}=\|g\|_{\infty}$. So $\|f\|=1$.

Is this correct or am I doing it wrong? Also, I'm not too sure about notation so any tips are welcome.

Comment: That notation using of $\inf$ is awkward. The norm is the infimum bound of $\|f(x)\|/\|x\|$, but when you write $\inf$ with something to the right it reads as taking infimum of what is to the right. A notation that expresses what you want to say can be $\sup_{\|x\|\leq1}\|f(x)\|$.

Comment: @plop Should I better write $\inf_{x\in C([a,b])}$ and put brackets around the whole term I want to have the inf of?

Comment: The full notation is $\sup \{ \|f(x)\| : x\in C([a,b]) , \|x\|\leq 1\}$. A reasonable shorthand is, as @plop suggests, $\sup {\|x\|\leq 1} \|f(x)\|$. It is a $\sup$ instead if an $\inf$, and the inequality on the norm is important, otherwise the result is infinite.